# Criteria builder and condition in the join

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3

I have this sql query

```
SELECT i.code
FROM income i
LEFT JOIN pub p ON i.pub_id = p.pub_id AND p.version = '1'
WHERE i.person_id =12345
```

I would like to convert this query with criteria builder

```
Join<Income, Pub> pubJoin = root.join("pub");
```